# How can I use an method from a collection as an generic method for other classes

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I’m locking for a way to use my function GetItem as an generic-Method for some other classes. These classes are based all from CBase and I use the method GetItem into nearly 20 classes. The only thing of difference into the 20 classes are the classtype. In this example is the classtype CLoad.

I would use the Function GetItem as an generic-method, but I doesn’t see a way to do that. At the moment I copy this function to every class.

I hope there is a better way.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsGenerics
{
    public class CLoadListe : Collection<CLoad>
    {
        ///<param name="Searchstring"> String nach dem die Lastenliste durchsucht werden soll </param>
        ///<param name="Parameter"> NAME für Lastenname, ALIASNAME oder DESCRIPTION</param>
        public CLoad GetItem(string Searchstring, string Parameter = "NAME")
        {
            if (this.Count == 0) return null;
            if (Searchstring.Length == 0) return null;
            switch (Parameter)   // Parameter auswerten
            {
                case ("NAME"): return this.Where(item => item.Name == Searchstring).FirstOrDefault();
                case ("DESCRIPTION"): return this.Where(item => item.Description == Searchstring).FirstOrDefault();
                default: throw new System.Exception($"Suchparameter {Parameter} nicht vorhanden");
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>Basisklasse für alle Elemente </summary>
    public class CBase
    {
        /// <summary> Elementname </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }
        /// <summary> Beschreibung </summary>
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    public class CKnoten : CBase { }
    public class COneNodeElement : CBase
    {
        /// <summary> KnotenOne des Elementes </summary>
        public CKnoten KnotenOne { get; set; }
        /// <summary> Schaltzustand am KnotenOne </summary>
        public bool SwitchOne { get; set; }
    }
    public class CLoad : COneNodeElement { }


}
```

Thanks
Steffen

Comment: look at interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a base class for your lists:

```
public abstract class CListe<T> : Collection<T>
    where T : CBase
{
    public T GetItem(string Searchstring, string Parameter = "NAME")
    {
        // As is...
    }
}
```

Now `LoadListe` is just:

```
public sealed CLoadListe : CListe<CLoad> { }
```

However I'd highlight few minor issues here:

- In C# usually classes are not prefixed with `C` then you *should* have `Liste`, `Load` and so on.
- Parameters are usually camelCase.
- You do not need a string parameter, what's for when you have `enum`?
- Your classes are all not-abstract and not-sealed. Make classes you don't want to instantiate `abstract` and classes you do not want to extend through inheritance `sealed`.
- Your tests for t`his.Count == 0` and `searchString.Length == 0` are useless, `this.Where()` will perform as required without them (it may be a an attempt of micro optimization but it will degrade common path performance). You may instead want to add argument checking (for example if `searchString` is `null` throw `ArgumentNullException`).
- Do not ever throw a generic `Exception` when you have a better exception type. In this case you may use `ArgumentException` (or `InvalidEnumArgumentException` if you switch to an `enum`).
- Given that I'd drop parameter `Parameter` you also are performing an ordinal comparison, not always what you may expect or you may be aware of. If you really have to stick with strings you'd better use `String.Equals()` with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public static class CBaseExtensions
{
    ///<param name="Searchstring"> String nach dem die Lastenliste durchsucht werden soll </param>
    ///<param name="Parameter"> NAME für Lastenname, ALIASNAME oder DESCRIPTION</param>
    public static T GetItem<T>(this Collection<T> self, string Searchstring, string Parameter = "NAME") where T : CBase
    {
        if (self.Count == 0) return null;
        if (Searchstring.Length == 0) return null;
        switch (Parameter)   // Parameter auswerten
        {
            case ("NAME"): return self.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == Searchstring);
            case ("DESCRIPTION"): return self.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Description == Searchstring);
            default: throw new System.Exception($"Suchparameter {Parameter} nicht vorhanden");
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it now like this:

```
var list = new CLoadListe();
var items = list.GetItem("searchstring", "parameter");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write an extension method

```
public static class CLoadExtension
{
    public static CLoad GetItem(this Collection<CLoad> coll, string Searchstring, string Parameter = "NAME")
    {
        if (this.Count == 0) return null;
            if (Searchstring.Length == 0) return null;
            switch (Parameter)   // Parameter auswerten
            {
                case ("NAME"): return this.Where(item => item.Name == Searchstring).FirstOrDefault();
                case ("DESCRIPTION"): return this.Where(item => item.Description == Searchstring).FirstOrDefault();
                default: throw new System.Exception($"Suchparameter {Parameter} nicht vorhanden");
            }
    }
}
```